# Uncaught ReferenceError: functions are not defined

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a Blackjack program in Javascript and I'm having issues finding the error in my code.  When I debug in Chrome it tells me when I click each of my buttons that the corresponding function is undefined.  I can't seem to find the error so hopefully you all can!  Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are missing a `}` for `...else if (playerscore > dealerscore... `.

Comment: @Deafsilver: For future reference: please provide executable examples. You may want to us JSFiddle for this, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/JcuKf/

Comment: Please debug, track down the problem, isolate code and post live demo if possible to reproduce the issue. Also I suggest reading about [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself). Maybe when you get it working you could seek advice at [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have a syntax error in your code, so none of the code in the script tag is executed.

You are missing a closing `}` for the last `if` statement in the last function.

Comment: Annnnnnnnd now I feel like an idiot.  Thank you very much for that haha.

Comment: We've all been there, @Deafsilver . . . sometimes you just need another pair of eyes to take a look.   :)